# What is syntax for creating a VPC in terraform for Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

Like how we have the command "azurerm_virtual_network" for the creation of a VPN. What would be the syntax for creating a VPC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question, but in my knowledge, in Azure, you can say to a certain extent that VNET *"is"* the equivalent of AWS VPC. Either you are trying to ask about another resource or there is a feature you've seen in AWS VPC that you don't find in Azure VNET.